# How to render data to chart in email

Tags: javascript, email, d3.js

This days I have a demand that shows some data in email. The data have been stored in MySQL, then I have to render this data to line chart or other chart and 
embed it in email every day(the data in every day is different).I want to make this process automatically. How do I achieve it? Some solution may be need.

I have searched from google and find a way: **D3.js** and **Phantomjs** and **Node.js**, D3.js renders the chart, Phantomjs makes the chart to image, Node.js serves as the server to render data in MySQL to D3 chart and serves as the image server.

But I can not determine this way can be achieved.How about the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to render SVG file using D3 using Node.js directly rather than going with PhantomJS. Most email clients will display SVG vector images, so you don't need PNG or JPEG

https://gist.github.com/Caged/6407459

Comment: thanks, but the d3-server.js in your link has a problem that haven't been handled.

Comment: I would advice against emailing SVG's, many clients do not support them. Have a google or even see other SO posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681562/svg-image-not-showing-in-html-email